# Set Navigation bar for multiple HTML page in google script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

Right now I have multiple pages (Page1, Page2, etc) button embedded in DoGet function. The code below is taken from the author on Stackoverflow and it like this:

```
function doGet(e) 
{
  //Logger.log('query params: ' + Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
  if(e.queryString !=='')
  {  
    switch(e.parameter.mode)
    {
      case 'page4':
        setPage('Page4')      
        return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page4')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page4"); 
        break;  
      case 'page3':
        setPage('Page3');        
        return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page3')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page3");
        break;
      case 'page2':
        setPage('Page2');        
        return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page2')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page2");
        break;  
      case 'page1':
         setPage('Page1');
         return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page1')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page1");
        break;
      default:
        setPage('Page1');
        return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page1')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page1");
        break;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    setPage('Page1');
    return HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile('Page1')
    .evaluate()
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setTitle("Page1");
  }
}

function getPageData()
{
  var s='';
  s+='<input type="button" value="Page1" onClick="getUrl(\'?mode=page1\');" />';
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Page2" onClick="getUrl(\'?mode=page2\');" />';
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Page3" onClick="getUrl(\'?mode=page3\');" />';
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Page4" onClick="getUrl(\'?mode=page4\');" />';
  var rObj={menu:s,title:getPage()};
  Logger.log(rObj);
  return rObj;
}
```

The final UI looks like this
[image]

If I click on Page 2, the top left buttons would disappear but I want to keep the Page 1, Page 2, Page 3, Page 4 button there as I navigate between the four pages. I am also trying to add style to make it a navigation bar for all the four pages. Any help here would be much appreciated!

Source of the code: [Multiple Forms, One Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55770386/multiple-forms-one-project/55770563#55770563)
Author: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55770563/7215091

Comment: It looks like you copied this from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, you can [edit], include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, mention the author's name, and [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed it. Please let me know if this looks good.

Comment: The original code doesn't seem to hide the navbar. You see probably doing something wrong.  Check browser console logs, when you click.